# How to get generated item ID while using Dependency Injection and Unit Of Work?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, unit-of-work

I am using ASP.NET MVC5, Entity Framework 6, Dependency Injection and Unit Of Work.

I am facing issue while saving a new item in the database. I am not able to get the newly generated ID of the just inserted item.

Below is a sample of my code, just to know more about my issue:

> Here's my service

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserRepository UserRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userRepository = UserRepository;
    }
    public int Create(UserDTO entity)
    {
        if(entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        entity = _userRepository.Add(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();

        return entity.UserID;
    }
}
```

> Here's my repository

```
public virtual TEntityDTO Add(TEntityDTO entity)
{
    var item = Mapper.Map<TEntityDTO, TEntity>(entity);
    var createItem = Mapper.Map<TEntity, TEntityDTO>(context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item));
    return createItem;
}
```

> Here's my unit of work

```
public int Commit()
{
    // Save changes with the default options
    return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please post a _minimal, complete, verifiable example_ that demonstrates the problem. If the problem is related to DI, your code doesn't show it (although I find it unlikely the problem is related to DI). If this is related to your EF binding, you are not showing your model. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know Entity Framework but the problem looks obvious to me.

The line `entity=_userRepository.Add(entity);` calls `Add` method of Repository. In your `Add` method in Repository, you are adding an entity and then **mapping** it back to DTO. You are then returning mapped DTO. Note that DTO is detached here from your entity. It cannot anymore reflect the changes in Entity.

Then in your service, you call `_unitOfWork.Commit();`. This flushes the changes to database and here actually the new ID is generated. This new ID is reflected in your entity. But as you are dealing with DTO which is no more connected to Entity, you cannot see that newly generated ID.

What is the solution then? I do not know, this depends on your overall architecture.

1. Return the entity without mapping it with DTO.
2. Commit inside repository instead of Service.